# Why does form ID get displayed to drupal_set_message?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm upgrading from 6 to 7 (thankless task!) and Ive noticed that in the admin section the name of any form that is on the page seems to get output to drupal_set_message (it appears in the green box) I thought this to be unusual but possibly deliberate on the part of the module author. However, in my custom module I have a form and when ever I go to the page the name of the form appears in the green status box.

Can anyone shed any light onto why this may be happening?

Comment: "Screen or it didn't happen" ;) But no, really, it never happened to me and I'd love to see how it looks. Maybe it would help us guess why. Also, can you `grep` your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be having [hook_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your code
possible code in your custom code will be

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form,&$form_state,$form_id) {
//just remove the below line to disable the message
drupal_set_message($form_id);


}
```

Comment: I cant believe I didnt spot this! you are indeed correct. I put it in my hook_form_alter when I was debugging something else and then completely forgot about it! good call.